# dislocker doesn't work after upgrade from 17.10 to 18.04

Tags: 18.04, shared-library

Any use of `dislocker` returns this error:

```
dislocker: error while loading shared libraries: libmbedcrypto.so.0:
 cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

How to fix it?

Comment: What is dislocker?

Answer (score 2):

I have finally did it.

Steps to get it to work:

1. add /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ to LD_LIBRARY_PATH:

   LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
   export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
2. in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ i have libmbedcrypto.so.2.8.0 so i had to create symlink as mentioned before by Elder

   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu$ sudo ln -sf libmbedcrypto.so.2.8.0 libmbedcrypto.so.0
3. after doing that there was also a problem  with libruby-2.3.so.2.3. Doing another symlink solved that problem to:

   sudo ln -sf libruby-2.5.so.2.5 libruby-2.3.so.2.3

After that dislocker is finally working and i can decrypt my windows bitlocker encrypted drives.

Comment: Thanks a lot, man!

Answer (score 1):

`libmbedcrypto.so` is contained within the [libmbedtls-dev](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libmbedtls-dev) package in the universe repository.

First [enable the universe repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository) if it isn't already.

Then issue the command `sudo apt install libmbedtls-dev`

You might need to create a softlink called `libmbedcrypto.so.0` linking to `libmbedcrypto.so` as mentioned [here.](https://github.com/shadowsocks/shadowsocks-libev/issues/1966)

Note: I haven't personally tested this approach but logically it would seem worth a try.